# Esp IDF memory mapped file

Tags: esp32, mmap, freertos, esp-idf

is there any similar functionality in ESP-IDF v5.1 (or any other version ) to this code?

the goal is to map **any file** with its **descriptor** `(FILE* fd)`

```
FILE *fd = fopen("test/sq/v/a/trip/12", "rb");
struct stat st;
if (fd != nullptr && stat("test/sq/v/a/trip/12", &st) == 0) {
  char *data = (char *)mmap(nullptr, st.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, fileno(fd), 0);
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    printf("%d", data[i]);
}
```

there are some **mmap** related function under   **`#include "esp_mmu_map.h"`**, like **`esp_mmu_map`** but i cant find how i should use them with a `file descriptor` like the above example. I also couldn't figure out if event this is possible on esp or not in the Documentation.